# Because Geany doesn't recognize python 3.8.2?

Tags: python-3.x, geany

Hello I just reinstalled the system to my PC and installed python 3.8.2 but when trying to run geany it gives me the following message

`/tmp/geany_run_script_CN6UO0.sh: 7: python: not found    program exited with code: 127`

I would like to receive instructions

Comment: Can you share your `$PATH` environment variable?

Comment: Well, in Linux I do not know how to demonstrate it or talk about the construction menu in geany

Comment: with ` echo$PATH`  returned the following ` /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin`

Comment: And is python really available in one of those locations?

Comment: @Mureinik  i'm really new to linux there are things i don't know

Comment: I know they are installed when I apply the code `ls /usr/bin/python*`  I get  usr/bin/python3           /usr/bin/python3-config      /usr/bin/pythontex
/usr/bin/python3.8         /usr/bin/python3-futurize
/usr/bin/python3.8-config  /usr/bin/python3-pasteurize

Comment: Go to the build menu and change python to python3 inside Set Build Commands -- My guess is your distribution did not set up a symlink python -> python3.8